# How to keep your feet from heating up during your run

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-shoes, foot-pain, foot-care

I have been running 5k since last month and slowly building up my pace. The only problem that I face is that my lower part of the feet heats up during my run. I wear *NIKE
DUAL FUSION RUN 3 MSL PRM BLACK RUNNING SHOES* and cotton ankle socks.

Before consulting a doctor, I felt I should share with the community :)

Any suggestions?

NB: FYI I can cover 5 km distance in 28-29 minutes at a constant pace.

Comment: And after the run? Any pain,discomfort,redness,...?

Comment: I suggest editing out the mention of the doctor because medical advice is not allowed, but "how to keep your feet from heating up during your run" is a great question (and would have been a good title).

Comment: Sounds good to me too..Updated! Thanks for the title :)

Comment: Are you intending to keep your shoes or are you open to alternate footwear?

Comment: What do you mean by "heating up"? Does your entire foot get warm? Lots of foot sweat? Or are just the soles of your feet getting hot?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: The lower part of the foot heats up. FYI I have no medical condition. Answer updated :)

Comment: I had this problem some years back - it turned out that I had a "fallen forefoot" (not entirely sure about the English term). A custom-made EVA insole helped solve the problem.

Comment: Just for reference, Tonny Madsen's question can be found at http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/what-to-do-against-a-burning-sensation-in-my-feet-during-long-runs?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and I might have figured out the answer:
The heat is caused by friction. This friction is produced because your feet can move within your shoe...so my suggestion is get some thicker, breathable socks.

Comment: That might be the solution. How about a thicker wollen socks?

Comment: Although, then more heat gets trapped...

Comment: Well, for me it worked. Just try it out

Comment: I will update tomorrow about the results :)

Comment: I like Mohair over wool. It has many of the same properties as wool and I find, for me, it does better at preventing blisters.

Comment: Just an update to my issue for everyone, my issue was solved when I used a thicker pair of socks. The only downside was that it got heated up pretty soon. But my primary issue was resolved. Thanks community!

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out thinner merino wool socks or a synthetic sock specific to 'cooling.' Merino wool and specific synthetics pull sweat from the feet and help keep them cooler. Generally speaking. For example the Smartwool PhD Run (Ultra) Lights or Wigwam Ultra Cools.

Even more specifically I'd look for thin double layer socks, which sounds thicker true. But, two thin double layers also help reduce friction (a source of heat).

I'm partial to the Wrightsock coolmesh II at the moment for this reason.

If changing your socks to something more cooling still doesn't help, then I'd blame the shoes.

Answer (score 1):

I can sympathize with your problem. My feet get really hot when I'm running as well. My solution for the problem was to move to [minimalist shoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalist_shoe), in my case, a set of [Xero Shoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xero_Shoes) sandals. They don't work for everyone — and they do necessitate learning a different running technique for most people as you no longer have artificial cushioning around your heel, but I personally find them much more comfortable.

Outside of that, my impulse is that you could probably try adding venting to your shoes by cutting holes, albeit at the loss of structural integrity and waterproofing.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to if your feet are rubbing or not, I find the socks I use make the difference.  I tried some short basic cotton socks and my feet get very hot.  Then I got some puma socks that are meant for running and breathe a lot (my shoes also breathe pretty well) and I noticed a major difference.  Make sure your shoes are good for your feet.  I'm not sure where you are located but there are running shops where they will look at you walk and recommend shoes as well as help you with the heat issue.  Where I live we have a place called fleet feet and they are great.

Answer (score 1):

Our feet absorb more force during running as compare to other body parts.So you should give extra care to your feet because foot  is the most frequently injured part of the body.Proper shoe selection should be there, once you purchase right shoes then you need to maintain them and replace them when they are worn out.

Answer (score 0):

Tie your shoes with a [Runners Knot](http://www.runnersworld.com/running-shoes/the-best-knot-for-your-running-shoes), if friction is the reason, friction as in movement of the feet in the shoes. It will keep your feet stable inside the shoe.

Comment: Can you provide more details or diagrams and _why_ this would help?